# Why won't my application in the iOS Simulator change to the current version in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When ever I make changes to my project in the Xcode storyboard, and relaunch my app in the iOS Simulator, the simulator displays an outdated version of my project.  What is happening?

In Xcode:
[image]

In the iOS Simulator:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- Cleaning your target before building. `shift-command-K`
- Reseting iOS Simulator ( on "iOS Simulator" menu, select "Reset Contents and Settings..."

Comment: Resetting iOS Simulator fixed it.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Everytime you build and run, XCode copies executable binary code and  resources (Xib's and media files, etc) to iDevice or simulator's directory as part of the app "installation" process. It doesn't transfer all the resources all the time, but only the ones that have been modified since the last run (for sake of efficiency). Sometimes, XCode makes less than perfect decision on which resources to copy over and you see old resources still being used. Resetting Contents deletes all the existing data and forces XCode to copy over everything.